# How to reference a value to a range of numbers in another list then have values returned from 2 different places where the value is found

Tags: vba, excel

I hope my title made some sense. In essence I am trying to do this with very little programming experience and I understand now that I very much need help. I have been attempting to use Visual Basic because I am trying to sort through a very large list of unrecognized genes. Overall, I am trying to check whether ANY of my "midpoint" (original gene location) values lies in-between any row's "startpoint" and "endpoint" (known gene locations). If it does, then I need both code and name returned to me somehow, even if it matches in more than one row. To make matters worse, it should only do this if its "midchrom" matches the respective row's "chrom".

The list happens to be 3k rows long, hence why I would like to do it this way. I hope I explained myself well enough.. An example of the list is copied at the bottom (I hope csv is fine, first time asking here). I have been able to write no code at all since I don't know how to approach the problem at all, and I've been at it for 2 days, so I have sadly nothing to post.

Any suggestions appreciated! Thank you!

```
midchrom,midpoint,   code,     chrom, name,  Startpoint, endpoint
chr1,    10052729.5, NM_018896,chr1,  Name1, 117328105,  117475235
chr1,10249243,NM_001177888,chr1,Name2,109035529,109052409
chr1,1103696.50,NM_001256327,chr1,Name3,125766078,125845734
chr1,1112610.00,NM_001256360,chr1,Name4,125766078,125845734
chr1,11947610.5,NM_198383,chr1,Name5,12470846.00,12460843.00
chr1,12249877.50,NM_198396,chr1,Name6,125766225,125845740
chr1,12383427.00,NM_001256325,chr1,Name7,109035526,109052415
chr1,12410787.50,NM_020084,chr1,Name8,12383158,12451963
chr1,12470843.00,NM_001003406,chr1,Name9,12383158,12451963
chr1,12494320.50,NM_009783,chr1,Name10,109035538,109052412
chr2,12529476.00,NM_171733,chr1,Name11,125766225,125845740
chr1,12809629.00,NM_001256334,chr1,Name12,125766078,125845734
chr1,12909892.00,NM_001256329,chr1,Name13,175711654,176178148
chr1,13200078,NM_001029326,chr1,Name14,175711654,176281155
chr13,13706259.5,NM_001256328,chr2,Name15,192931857,192942982
chr1,1451461.5,NM_001193140,chr2,Name16,192931857,192942982
chr1,14004645.5,NM_001256359,chr1,Name17,176007934,176281155
chr1,15906995,NM_031601,chr1,Name18,142223122,142606517
chr1,15956960.5,NM_001044308,chr13,Name19,13709000,13706230
```

Comment: Show us where you are stuck or what you having problems with.

Comment: @pnuts: even the matrix version with excel formula would be quite a challenge...

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I understand I may have been off topic, not my intention, I just had absolutely no progress to post with the problem that made actual sense. I have very little knowledge of how to go about these things, and I am slowly learning, but this was a one time problem I needed to solve relatively soon. Again, sorry if I didn't follow standard protocol and thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pnuts suggested, you can do this without VBA by creating a matrix:

[image]

1. Add two rows above your data
2. Tranpose columns "midchrom", "midpoint" and "name" to top-right of your data as in the screenshot. use Paste Special->Values & Transpose
3. Place the following formula in the top left of the new "table/matrix": `=IF(AND(H$1=$D4,H$2>=$F4,H$2<=$G4),H$3,"")` - and copy it down and across. If it's 3k gene, the calculation might take a bit, but shouldn't be too long
4. Every row now shows the names of all genes whose' midpoints lay in between the start- and endpoint of the row's gene (assuming it the same chromatin)

Here's the [sample file](https://mega.co.nz/#!2FpwUDDQ!c6wsA2nv9uzt-OgR0FYsH1ak434tBaoa8K1vW8GROf4).